# How to prevent user from entering decimal value in c?

Tags: c

I want the user to enter an int 1, 2 or 3. How do I prevent decimals from being entered and crashing the program?

Comment: Is this a windows program? Console application on Linux or Windows?

Comment: atoi() ...??? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: the imediate answer is: **test the input**
but without some code is hard the give you any specific directions

Comment: If you don't have control over the exact characters typed by the user (*e.g.*, in a Windows input element) then the way to keep bad input from crashing your program is to properly check the string for what you want before you assume it's what you want.

Comment: Please do not edit everything out of all your questions.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you want to practice defensive programming. Assume the user will enter wrong or malicious input and sanitize it properly. In this case, that means assume the user could enter anything, try to parse an int out of it, if possible, and if not, give the user an error message saying that they entered the input incorrectly.

In code, this means reading a line of input, perhaps with `fgets()` if you are using bog-standard C for a console/terminal application, and using a function like `atoi()` or `strtol()`. These will parse the input string and return an integer value. If there is invalid data in the input, they won't flag it. You'll have to do that yourself. This can easily be done by looping through the string, looking for any characters that are not digits. If you find any, print an error message to the user.

If you want any additional details, I can provide them. I will not provide a pile of ready-to-use code, however.

Answer (score 1):

OP did not provide much detail other than a simple 1-2-3.  Follows is a simple solution

```
// Return 1, 2 or 3 on good input
// else return 0
int Get123() {
  int c = fgetc(stdin);
  if ((c < '1') || (c > '3')) {
    return 0;
  }
  return c - '0';
}
```